# Can we add more than 5 input contexts in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

[image]

Can we add more than 5 input contexts in dialogflow ? I am getting above error while trying to add more than 5 input contexts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to use more than 5 input contexts in a single intent.

Even when you enter 5 input contexts then all 5 input context has to be active otherwise you will not get the response.